# why are middlewares in app.use() is executed each time irrespective of the url?

Tags: node.js, express

The **middlewares** inside the **app.use('/',function)** is executed each time **irrespective of the url**. For eg: if the client request **localhost:8080/about** the middlewares present inside the app.use('/', function) also gets executed since the **request path is** "/**about**".

hereby i have shared the codes & comment my doubts as well

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get('/about', (req,res,next)=>{
    console.info('this is from app.get()');
    next(); /* using res.end() helps me but why get('/about') didn't works */
});

app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.info('this is from app.use() and it will be executed irrespective of the url');
    next();
});

let port = app.listen(8080,(err)=>{
    console.info('the server is started from port: ', port.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.use('/')` will apply to every route that starts with `/` which means literally every route will match hence that behavior.

If you only want to have it on the exact `/` path, maybe `app.all('/')` could solve your problem.